# How do I sort structures (consisting of several different elements) using qsort?

Tags: c++, list, sorting, struct, qsort

Specifically it's about a list in a .txt file,"char Name"(jmeno) "char Surname"(prijmeni) "float Average"(prumer) --> students with average of their grades (grading 1-5), sorted with qsort according to the average.

My code so far looks like this:

```
FILE *otevriSoubor(char *jmeno, char* mode)
{
    FILE *soubor;
    soubor = fopen(jmeno, mode);
    if (!soubor)
    {
        printf("spatne jmeno souboru\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    return soubor;
}
int srovnaniprumeru(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int c = ((Student *) a)->prumer;
    int d = ((Student *) b)->prumer;
    if (c > d) return -1;
    if (c < d) return 1;
    return 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    typedef struct
    {
        char jmeno[MAXDELKA];
        char prijmeni[MAXDELKA];
        float prumer;
    } Student;
    qsort(bakaweb, 5, sizeof(Student), srovnaniprumeru);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++ prefer `std::sort` instead of `qsort`.

Comment: Looks like an obvious mistagging to me. OP's code looks like C.

Comment: And no need for the `typedef struct {...} name;` trick. `struct Name{...};` does the deed.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, prefer to use `std::string` instead of `char` arrays.

Comment: Also, since `Student` is used in functions outside of `main`, you should move the `struct` definition to before the first function that uses it (or maybe better, place it into a separate header file).

Comment: IMHO, you don't need function `otevriSoubor`.  Place the contents in the `main` function.  The overhead of calling the function may be more effort by the program than the work it provides, (or declare it as `inline`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat almost totally agree with you, but so many people are taught C and told it's C++ that I kinda take their word for it when they tag C++ and try to help them out.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `qsort` instead of `std::sort`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That's silly. Compilers inline small functions automatically, but in this case it doesn't even matter: Opening a file is not a performance critical operation.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the program except for missing variables and  awkward programming style.   Did you find anything wrong? Why asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Here are areas for improvement:

- Your code is incomplete: you do not read the student details. You can use `fscanf()` for that.
- You sort based on the conversion of the grades to `int`.  This might be incorrect if the grades are not whole numbers.

Complete your code and fix your sorting function this way:

```
int srovnaniprumeru(const void *a, const void *b) {
    float c = ((const Student *)a)->prumer;
    float d = ((const Student *)b)->prumer;
    if (c > d) return -1;
    if (c < d) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```